# How can I increase Angular/Node performance by making one API call instead of several?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, angular-services

Using Angular/Node to build a Proof of Concept project. I have accomplished on finishing the first task which is "making it work." Since the MVP works, I now need to focus on performance. The latency is really really bad and I don't know how to approach it or fix it. Tried various methods but no luck.

**Overview:**

Using Node Server to call an external API for Data in JSON format. Using Angular Service to make 5 API calls and rendering data on Angular Controller. Is there a way I can only make one API call instead of 5? Since it is making 5 API call the CPU processing is at 90% on the server side and following is the Client performance:

[image]

Comment: Why make 5 calls? Couldn't you return all the data in one call? Or if there is some reason why you need 5 separate APIs, why don't you make a 6th API that consolidates all 5 other APIs into a single call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it takes X amount of time to collect the results for one API call, then you are stuck with X * 5 times to collect the results for five API calls. If you cannot change the API to consolidate it, at least you can cut down on waiting for round trips across the network by sending all five API calls at the same time (i.e. one right after the other, asynchronously).

That is, if X = (N * 2) + P for twice the network travel, plus processing, then instead of 5 * ((N * 2) + P) you could see something like (N * 2) + (5 * P). It may still be that the server processes them one at a time, but you don't have the travel time on the network in between the requests.

If the server is not busy, and has multiple cores, and is multi-threaded or multi-process, and database locking is in your favor, you might see some concurrency between the five competing requests and the 5 * P could be less.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in a well-crafted form. Ended up consolidating API calls in 1.